# Sqlalchemy 2.0 - Query builder in model (like in Rails ActiveRecord)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In the Rails ActiveRecord formalism, you can define pieces of a query (where clauses, etc) like this in the model:

```rb
class Shirt < ActiveRecord::Base    
   scope :red, -> { where(color: 'red') }
   scope :dry_clean_only, -> { where('dry_clean_only = ?', true) }
end
```

And then you can do:

```rb
@shirts = Shirt.red.dry_clean_only
```

Now, in Sqlalchemy 2.0, instead of an "ActiveRecord", we have a "Model" class.

```py
class Shirt(DeclarativeBase)
  id : Mapped[int] = mapped_column(primary_key=True,index=True)
  color : Mapped[str]
  dry_clean_only : Mapped[bool]
```

Is there any way to define "pieces" of queries in the model (as `@classmethods` or whatever) so that we can "stack" them up to get a complete query, replicating the functionality from Rails?

Such as:

```
results = Shirt.red().dry_clean_only()  # ??? Way to do this?
```

Comment: I've been wishing for this a lot, but I don't think it exists yet. You can use @hybrid_property, then `select(Shirt).filter(Shirt.red, Shirt.dry_clean_only)`, but it's much less clean.